# How to match valgrind thread ID with gettid() or pthread_self()

Tags: linux, valgrind

The thread ID shown by Valgrind in warning/error message seems to be self generated. It doesn't match the thread ID from gettid() or pthread_self(). Please find the attached valgrind warning log. In this case how can I match the valgrind warning to my own thread, especially when the valgrind error doesn't show the full stack?

```
[debug] [12034:12525] zwp_interfaces_time.c:221 zwp_time_report_handler(): time callback done
[function] [12034:12426] zwp_interfaces.c:220 zwp_interfaces_report_wait(): Function started
[debug] [12034:12426] zwp_interfaces.c:229 zwp_interfaces_report_wait(): 1
[debug] [12034:12525] zwp_interfaces_time.c:245 zwp_time_date_report_handler(): date callback start
[debug] [12034:12426] zwp_interfaces.c:267 zwp_interfaces_report_wait(): 4
==12034== Thread 5:
==12034== Invalid write of size 4
==12034==    at 0x4DCB36E: ??? (in /home/debian/projecta/install/apr/lib/libapr-1.so.0.5.2)
==12034==  Address 0x77a69d8 is on thread 5's stack
==12034==  16 bytes below stack pointer
==12034==
==12034== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==12034==    at 0x4DCB518: ??? (in /home/debian/projecta/install/apr/lib/libapr-1.so.0.5.2)
==12034==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==12034==    at 0x4DCB36E: ??? (in /home/debian/projecta/install/apr/lib/libapr-1.so.0.5.2)
==12034==
==12034== Use of uninitialised value of size 4
==12034==    at 0x4DCB51A: ??? (in /home/debian/projecta/install/apr/lib/libapr-1.so.0.5.2)
==12034==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==12034==    at 0x4DCB36E: ??? (in /home/debian/projecta/install/apr/lib/libapr-1.so.0.5.2)
==12034==
==12034== Use of uninitialised value of size 4
==12034==    at 0x4DCB382: ??? (in /home/debian/projecta/install/apr/lib/libapr-1.so.0.5.2)
==12034==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==12034==    at 0x4DCB36E: ??? (in /home/debian/projecta/install/apr/lib/libapr-1.so.0.5.2)
==12034==
[debug] [12034:12429] zwp_interfaces.c:397 zwp_execute_messages(): 1
```

Valgrind thread ID is 5. My thread ID (from `syscall(SYS_gettid)`) is 12525, 12426, 12429 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind log/message output does not show the OS thread id.
It should be relatively trivial to implement e.g. a new command line option:

```
   --show-lwpid=yes|no
```

to optionally add the lwpid in the log/message output.
So, I suggest to file a bug/wish on valgrind bugzilla, and that
might increase the probability to have this feature appearing in the soon
to be released new version :).

In the meantime, if the threads are started right at the beginning of
the process execution, you might show the list of threads and the link
with the OS thread id by using the gdb monitor command 'v.info scheduler'.

E.g. from the shell, you can do:

```
vgdb v.info scheduler
```

You can also do that from gdb, or from within your code.

Comment: Thanks @phd. The program is not going to run under GDB under general testing scenario. You mentioned that the command can be run within my code. But I assume in that case the program is still need to run under GDB?

Comment: @AngelaYan : no, there is no need to run it under gdb. You can run the valgrind monitor requests from within your program at any moment. And you can from the shell use vgdb at any moment. See http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver-commandhandling for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Had a chat with Valgrind dev/user via the IRC channel. Valgrind thread ID is self generating number that starts from 1. It has no relation to the system thread ID. Thanks for one of the Valgrind dev/user in the channel to suggest to assign name to the thread. I have tried the method and it worked! This is my code:

```
//Start of each thread
char current_thread_name[16] = { 0 };

sprintf(current_thread_name, "tid[%ld]", syscall(SYS_gettid));

if(prctl(PR_SET_NAME, current_thread_name) == -1)  goto l_err_set_thread_name;

Debug_print("Current thread name: %s", current_thread_name);
```

Have '-v' in valgrind option to print out thread name during error reporting and voila!